# Python's platform module does not detect windows 10

Tags: python, windows

I am working on Windows 10 presently and need to put some code if the platform is Windows 10. So, I checked in python docs and read about platform module. This is what the documentation says :

> `platform.win32_ver(release='', version='', csd='', ptype='')`:
>   Get additional version information from the Windows Registry and return a tuple (release, version, csd, ptype) referring to OS release, version number, CSD level (service pack) and OS type (multi/single processor)

When I tried the same function on my Windows 10 machine I got below :

```
>>> platform.win32_ver(）
('8', '6.2.9200', '', u'Multiprocessor Free')
```

But, I was expecting the release to be 10 instead of 8.

So, any idea if I am missing something here ?

Also, can somebody please tell me if there exists any other way to detect if the windows platform is Windows 10 ?

Comment: And does that tuple reflect what's actually in the registry?

Comment: Seems a fix is scheduled to make it into Python 2.7.11 for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33436827/2448495 – to be released in December, 2015.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does platform.release() return "8" in Windows 10?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33431155/why-does-platform-release-return-8-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is python uses GetVersionEx to determine the version.

As you can read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451(v=vs.85).aspx), Microsoft doesn't support this anymore and offers a different API.

However, you can always call the new API yourself, or check the registry value at HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion.

You can also use WMI to get the Win32_OperatingSystem instance.

I'd also like to note that specific version checking is generally considered a bad practice.