# Why does platform.release() return "8" in Windows 10?

Tags: python, version, windows-10

I run this on my Windows 10 workstation:

```
import platform
print platform.release()
> 8
```

I'm somewhat perplexed. Should the response not have been "10" as I'm on Windows 10?

Comment: I'm pretty sure its because W10 is the 8th windows release.. Not sure if I've counted wrong though

Comment: Because W10 is named by marketers, and `platform.release()` is done by developers ;) further highlighting the eternal knowledge gap between marketing gimmicks and the real world.

Comment: This was fixed in Python 2.7.11, where `platform.release()` returns `10` on Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some digging...

[An issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue16176) was resolved for Python 2.7.10 according to its [release notes](https://hg.python.org/cpython/raw-file/15c95b7d81dc/Misc/NEWS):

> - Issue #16176: Properly identify Windows 8 via platform.platform()

However, with Windows 10 you still don't get the proper response. For this, a fix was created in late September, 2015: https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/2f57270374f7

As this was performed after the 2.7.10 release (released in late May, 2015), this will hopefully make it into a future release. Right now it should make it into 2.7.11 which is scheduled for a December 2015 release.

The fix makes `platform` read the Windows version from kernel32.dll to avoid compatibility issues.

A workaround right now could be to execute the `ver` command if the system is Windows based, and then parse the response manually.

**EDIT**:Indeed, this was fixed in Python 2.7.11:

```
import platform
print platform.release()
> 10
```